# Pursuing pluralist purpura

Tags: halacha, rishonim, techeles

According to most *[rishonim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rishonim)* (and the simplest read of the extant Talmudic texts) the *tekhelet* string is dyed in its entirety. However, the Rambam maintains that only half the string is dyed such that, when tied, only one of the eight hanging fringes are blue. If one dyed only half the string but tied the knot such that some of the blue was on the white side past the knot, would that be valid according to both views? Similarly, is the *tekhelet* of most *rishonim* valid *b'dieved* according to the Rambam and vice versa?

Comment: This seems unlikely. Rambam seems to be aiming for white in the core and blue on the outside of the winding. Tos, Raavad etc. are all counting whole strings and it's very unclear what they would think of a half died string, if they even considered the possibility (it's quite bizarre a priori).

Comment: @DoubleAA I ask because, at least with regard to lvanim, if the string break up to close to the knot, it's still kasher. What about with tekheles? And if it's the case with tekheles as well, does the fact that the string is present but dyed differently make it worse than if it wasn't there at all? (As far as the blue outside/white core according to the Rambam - is that b'dieved? I assume everyone agrees you just need 1 (double)knot and nothing more to be fulfill the d'oraitta...

Comment: Wait which knot are you talking about?

Comment: The first one, right up against the beged - if memory serves ;) which in this case it might knot.